# JscrollPane scroll easing?

Tags: jquery, easing

I've been looking into scroll easing in jquery, however I cannot seem to get this to work. Edit: I cannot get the *easing* properties to work. The scrolling is still static when scrolling with the mousewheel.

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
    animateScroll : true,
    animateDuration : 1000,
    animateEase : 'swing'
});
```

I'm testing this on FF16, [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuQK3/1/).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: It looks like he does have these options listed in the settings, but I cannot find a working example of them. - http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html

Are you including jQuery easing in your program? http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

It does however look like you can alter the wheelSpeed and some other options which may be of some use to you: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html